# Can I make any apps for Android Auto?

Tags: android, android-auto

I'm new with Android Auto and I have a queation. I have an app that the user only have to select items and pay. Can brings my app to Android Auto? Because I was searching a lot and I only find examples for media and messages apps. Studing the examples in the SDK of the media and messages, they not provide a layout for the Android Auto app.

Comment: (_Off topic comment_) So shop while driving? I wonder if that is safe and would ever pass their [review mechanism](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/auto.html#track_review).

Comment: Yeah, but the user will only be able to buy near the shop. (In the parking)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android Auto as of now supports only Media and Messaging Apps integration.

Comment: +1 Yep. Still is. I'm not sure if they're still planning to provide further customization for different kinds of apps for this.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, but currently the custom app SDK is private - you have to ask Google for access to it.

https://www.google.com/design/spec-auto/custom-apps/custom-app-anatomy.html#custom-app-anatomy-structure