# Build Custom App for Android Auto

Tags: android, android-auto

I am searching a method to build custom app for android Auto (Which is not a media app nor messaging app)

Exactly like [RoboCharge](https://www.google.com/design/spec-auto/branding/expressing-your-brand.html#)

Can someone give some directions for building such app.

N.B I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35455604/can-i-make-any-apps-for-android-auto) question, but my app will be very simple and will not distract the driver.

Comment: Not possible as of now.

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't allow to create custom apps to 3rd parties, yet.
You have to contact them and they will give you a new SDK