# Creating a 3rd party android automotive application

Tags: android, android-automotive

I am looking to create a 3rd party android automotive of our currently existing android mobile application. The application will not be listed on the play store it is just for internal use. The issue that I am facing is that the SDK is limited and it seems that I can only create applications from a set of templates (Navigation, Media, Messaging). My mobile application uses its own custom map and functionalities. I checked that people used to create 3rd party apps before but google revoked access to this 3rd party sdk and that I have to ask google for access.
[Can I make any apps for Android Auto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35455604/can-i-make-any-apps-for-android-auto)

Also, by going through the docs it's stated here "In order for your app to run on a real head unit (not the desktop head unit we provide), your app must be distributed through the Google Play Store."https://developer.android.com/training/cars/apps/auto#car-head-unit

If anyone can shed light on this whether custom apps are possible now for Android Auto and whether we have to go through the play store in order to use the app in a real head unit.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with the wording of this question, so let's first clarify the differences between `Android Auto` and `Android Automotive`.

- Android Auto is basically the projected mode. This means apps run on your phone and show on the head unit display (assuming your phone is connected to the car head unit).
- Android Automotive is referred to the embedded mode. It is actually Android running as an independent OS in the head unit of the car.

So, with this in mind:

if you want to add support for Android Auto to your existing app, you can do so by using the `androidx.car.app` library. It provides you with some templates to build the UI/UX. This is the only way to get your app published on Google Play and distribute to other users. Even if you don't want to distribute the app on Google Play, I believe using templates is the only way to build an Android Auto app at the moment.

If what you want is to target Android Automotive, I bet you can run your current mobile app in the Android Automotive emulator. Again, here the only way to publish your app on Google Play is by relying on `androidx.car.app`. If you build your own UI without using those templates, your only possibility at the time of writing is to distribute it via third party app stores (or convince Google, ;p).

Comment: Thank you for the insights. As I mentioned, it will be for internal use aka the drivers of the company. Do we still have to go through google play or is it possible that we install on the headunit someone via usb or something?

Comment: If it is for Android Auto support, what you will get in the end is the same mobile apk you have now, which should include the Android Auto support you need to add. That apk running on your phone should display on the DHU when connecting the phone via usb.
What I am unsure is if your app under development would work on a real car supporting Android Auto. (Most probably there are some restrictions to this)